Grounding - Confused
Building a single-story house, my radio shack will be in a bedroom that my wife has graciously, without complaining, agreed to let me use. I am confused about grounding, the articles and advice I have read seem to contradict.
As it stands now, the service panel ground to earth is via rebar into the foundation. It's code, it's accepted by the building inspector, and nothing to be done about that. The service panel will also have whole house surge protector.
To eliminate interference from other home appliances, motors etc, I will home run a separate circuit from the service panel to the shack on its own breaker. All good so far.
Some sources say that a separate ground rod is needed for the transceiver and other equipment. I understand the difference between a spider to a single point ground and will avoid a common bus that would induce an induction ground loop in the shack.
Some sources says that bonding a shack ground rod to the service panel will also create a ground loop. Saying that the equipment is already grounded by the third grounding prong on modern electrical plugs. This infers that a separate ground rod for the shack (not talking about the antenna here) is not needed.  As mentioned, other sources insist on a separate ground rod.
Question is: to 1. ground rod to transceiver and equipment only, or 2. ground rod and bond to the service panel, or 3. be content with the dedicated AC circuit?
BTW - ARRL site has not be definitive on this problem.
Thanks for your time and help.
-DL KK7NTU

Welcome to the site! You should check out this answer to a very similar question.

Welcome! As webmarc says there are many answers about this to browse - perhaps read some and then propose a detailed design for comment / criticism.  The electrical code also has something to say about gronding of antennas, and how the cables enter the house. Finally please ignore any complaints about "ground loops" - 99% of the time the term is misused, what someone usually means is "current on the ground wire causing mains hum" which is solved by More grounding, not Less. A Ground Mesh or Ground Web with everything interconnected is almost always better for lightning, RF and safety purposes.

Search for the Motorola R56 publication online.
The 2017 version has pictures that make things clearer than older versions.
The R56 requirements are for high availability radio installation like 911 centers so it is a bit of overkill for a ham radio operator.
However it lists all of the references like NEC, lightning protection,etc and outlines what is correct for radio installations.
You will get a lot of opinions from people, some outdated and some are just plain wrong.

Thanks for the R56 suggestion, it's a very thorough document! I found a copy at repeater-builder.com.
